# Fragment still there (or recreated) after configuration change from landscape to portrait

Tags: android, master-detail

### tl;dr

In a master detail flow on tablet in landscape, when changing configuration to portrait mode: the detail fragment is recreated (although not visible). I do not want that to happen. Only the master list activity shall be visible.

**How can I prevent that the detail fragment/video is recreated when changing configuration from landscape to portrait on a tablet?**

---

### long version

I have a curious case on my Android [baking app](https://github.com/Elyasin/baking-app) - an project I am doing for a course.

I implemented the master/detail flow (the Android Studio template). When I am in landscape mode the app functions as expected as far as I could test it.
However when I am in portrait mode (after rotating from the landscape while playing the video) I realise that the video continues playing. It seems to me that the fragment is recreated; I could not figure out how and why that happens.

The master activity is basically a recycler view displaying a list of items. The first item is about the ingredients and the rest is the steps of the recipe.
When I click on an item (ingredients in the image example below) the fragment loads the corresponding fragment. So far all is good.

The relevant code is in the `RecipeStepAdapter`. Since we are on tablet and landscape it is the 2 pane mode part that is executing.:

```
    //Click on item -> display the item
    //2 pane mode uses fragment
    //1 pane mode launches activity
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(
            view -> {
                List<Step> steps = mRecipe.getSteps();
                Step step = steps.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                if (mTwoPane) {

                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putInt(RecipeStepDetailFragment.step_number_key, step.getStepNo());
                    arguments.putString(RecipeStepDetailFragment.step_description_key, step.getDescription());
                    arguments.putParcelableArrayList(
                            RecipeStepDetailFragment.list_of_ingredients_key,
                            IngredientParcelable.makeParcelable(mRecipe.getIngredients())
                    );
                    arguments.putString(
                            RecipeStepDetailFragment.video_url_key,
                            !TextUtils.isEmpty(step.getVideoURL()) ? step.getVideoURL() : step.getThumbnailURL()
                    );

                    RecipeStepDetailFragment fragment = new RecipeStepDetailFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                    mParentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.recipe_step_detail_container, fragment)
                            .commit();

                } else {
                    Context context = view.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecipeStepDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(RECIPE_ID_KEY, step.getRecipeID());
                    intent.putExtra(RECIPE_STEP_NO_KEY, step.getStepNo());
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
    );
```

[image: Landscape mode of master/detail flow]

Now when I rotate to portrait, visually the correct master list view is displayed. However, I can hear the video continue.
I believe the fragment is just recreated from a saved instance probably. Not sure though, I am still in the process to understand it...
So far I think the `RecipeStepListActivity` (master list activity) is destroyed and recreated to display the view for portrait mode.
At the same time the detail fragment of the landscape mode is recreated although I expected it not to.

The master list activity merely deals with recycler view, adapter and data retrieval. I have no reason to believe something is wrong here. For reference.

```
package de.shaladi.bakingapp.ui;

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import de.shaladi.bakingapp.R;
import de.shaladi.bakingapp.adapters.RecipeStepAdapter;
import de.shaladi.bakingapp.db.RecipeDatabase;
import de.shaladi.bakingapp.viewmodel.RecipeStepListViewModelFactory;
import de.shaladi.bakingapp.viewmodel.RecipeStepViewModel;

/**
 * An activity representing a list of Instructions. This activity
 * has different presentations for handset and tablet-size devices. On
 * handsets, the activity presents a list of items, which when touched,
 * lead to a {@link RecipeStepDetailActivity} representing
 * item details. On tablets, the activity presents the list of items and
 * item details side-by-side using two vertical panes.
 */
public class RecipeStepsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = RecipeStepsListActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
     * device.
     */
    private boolean mTwoPane;

    private int mRecipeId;

    private RecipeStepAdapter mRecipeStepAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_steps_list);

        if (getIntent().hasExtra(MainActivity.RECIPE_ID_KEY)) {

            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }

            if (findViewById(R.id.recipe_step_detail_container) != null) {
                // The detail container view will be present only in the
                // large-screen layouts (res/values-w900dp).
                // If this view is present, then the
                // activity should be in two-pane mode.
                mTwoPane = true;
            }


            mRecipeId = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.RECIPE_ID_KEY, -1);
            if (mRecipeId == -1)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Recipe ID should be > 0.");


            RecipeDatabase db = RecipeDatabase.getsInstance(this);
            RecipeStepListViewModelFactory factory = new RecipeStepListViewModelFactory(db, mRecipeId);
            RecipeStepViewModel viewModel =
                    ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(RecipeStepViewModel.class);
            viewModel.getRecipe().observe(this, recipe -> {
                mRecipeStepAdapter.setRecipe(recipe);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(recipe.getName());
            });


            RecyclerView mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recipe_steps_list);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

            mRecipeStepAdapter = new RecipeStepAdapter(
                    this,
                    mTwoPane);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecipeStepAdapter);


        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Intent does not have an 'extra'. Recipe object cannot be retrieved. Activity ended.");
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Intent does not have an 'extra'. Recipe object cannot be retrieved. Activity ended.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(MainActivity.RECIPE_ID_KEY, mRecipeId);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

[image: Portrait mode]

I hope I explained the essence clearly. My question is:

**How can I prevent that the detail fragment/video is recreated when changing configuration from landscape to portrait on a tablet?**

Answer (score 0):

I am sure now that the behaviour is as per design. To test this simply create a Master/Detail flow app with Android Studio and log some output at the events onCreate, onCreateView, onStart, onResume, onPause, onStop, etc.

A better solution is not to prevent the fragment/video to be recreated or kept in memory, but instead to stop the player in that case.

So in my case if the fragment is not visible then ensure the video does not start playing automatically. I added this in the `onPause`/`onStop` method/s.

```
    if (!this.isVisible()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Fragment not visible. mPlayWhenReady set to false");
        mPlayWhenReady = false;
    }
```